# Finding words in a string that start with number (Regex)

Tags: regex

I need to find words in a string that start with number(i.e digit)

In following string:

```
1st 2nd 3rd a56b 5th 6th ***7th
```

The words 1st 2nd 3rd 5th 6th should be returned.

I tried with the regex:

```
(\b[^ a-zA-Z ^ *]+(th|rd|st|nd))+
```

But this regex returns the words not starting with alphabets but can't handle the cases when word starts with special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the current string, you may use a pattern like

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:th|rd|st|nd)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TOB4Di/1)

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` - a location at the start of a string or after a whitespace
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:th|rd|st|nd)` - one of the four alternatives
- `\b` - a word boundary.

If you plan to match any 0+ non-whitespace chars after a digit that is preceded with a whitespace or is at the start of a string, use

```
(?<!\S)\d\S*
```

where `\S*` will match any 0+ non-whitespace chars.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Y7xeO/1).

**NOTE**: In case the lookbehind is not supported, replace `(?<!\S)` with `(?:^|\s)` and also wrap the rest of the pattern with a capturing group to access the latter later:

```
(?:^|\s)(\d\S*)
```

and the value will be in Group 1.

Comment: it's better replace \b with (?!\S), other wise 8th**, will match too

Comment: @ShenYudong Perhaps, but that is probably expected. The second variant is just an addition.

Answer (score 0):

To get word which is starting with number/digit and ending with `th/st/nd/rd` you can try this.

```
((?<!\S)(\d+)(th|rd|nd|st))
```

`(?<!\S)` detects the word's starting position

`\d+` matches 1 or more digits

`th|rd|st|nd` matches one among those 4.

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/8Y7xeO/2)